# How to avoid duplicate connection names? (32) Connection 'Auto Ethernet' is already active on enpXXX

Tags: ubuntu, udev, networkmanager, network-namespaces

Is there any way that I can make networkmanager to assign some unique names or device derrived name instead of `Auto Ethernet` so that we can avoid the names conflict?

After I've upgraded to Ubuntu Vivid which uses systemd(though I'm not sure if it's directly related or it's just a bug / regression of network-manager) both of my mobile broadband devices get the "Auth Ethernet" name and are unable to get connected simultaneously.

I can temporarry fix it using  `nmcli con add type ethernet con-name my-office ifname ens3` but I would rather like to have network-manager handle this automatically (i.e. assign a random / unique conn name).

Use case:

I have two broadband USB devices and I need to connect to both of them. The issue is that NetworkManager displays them both as `Auto Ethernet` (duplicate in the network manager applet) and when I try to connect to the second network it errors out `(32) Connection 'Auto Ethernet' is already active on enp0s20u`. 
  When I try to "edit" the connections it displays only one `Auto Ethernet` connection.

`/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` also lists only one `Auto Ethernet`

Answer (score 0):

Disable your Network Manager and Configure the devices using files defined in /etc/network/interfaces

you can also rename the device name using udev rules as

**Using Udev rules to rename the devices**

```
cd /etc/udev/rules.d/
cat 70-persistent-net.rules
```

edit the 70-persistent-net.rules to change the name of PCI Devices in  your case USB device and connect it

Comment: That's not really convenient because the mobilebroadband devices are not easy to configure. I also loose the Predictable Network Name and any networkd/systemd configuration if I add 70-persistent-net.rules